# ERROR: subquery uses ungrouped column "shops.id" from outer query

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'm encountering an error for the below query:

> ```
> ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "shops.id" from outer query
> LINE 8:             WHERE target_id = shops.id AND type = 'started_d...
> ```

My query is:

```
SELECT  localities.name AS "City", 
        COUNT(shops) AS "Shops",
        CAST(AVG(shops.rating_cache) AS decimal(10, 2)) AS "Rating",
        SUM(shops.product_count_cache) AS "Products",
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM customer_events
            WHERE target_id = shops.id AND type = 'started_directions'
        ) AS "Visites"
FROM shops
LEFT JOIN localities ON localities.id = shops.locality_id
WHERE shops.locality_id
IN (
    SELECT cast(unnest as uuid) 
    FROM
     unnest(string_to_array('9c57227a-8f4e-44e0-a3a8-1439c25bf2e5,8f285bca-baec-442e-8a21-e067b75d8f13', ','))
) AND shops.onboarding_status = 'ready'

GROUP BY localities.name
```

First four selected and calculated columns are working but the 5th which counts the number of `customer_events` for the current row's `localities.id` doesn't work.

The column `target_id` is a foreign key to `shops.id`.

Any idea how to make my column count work?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a db fiddle, it would make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correlated subquery to get the count for `"Visites"` uses the un-aggregated column `shops.id` - just like the error message is trying to tell you.

You need to work with an aggregated value instead. This fixes the error:

```
SELECT l.name AS "City"
     , count(shops) AS "Shops"
     , avg(s.rating_cache)::decimal(10, 2) AS "Rating"
     , sum(s.product_count_cache) AS "Products"
     , ( SELECT count(*)
         FROM   customer_events c
         WHERE  c.target_id = min(s.id)              -- !!!
         AND    c.type = 'started_directions'
       ) AS "Visites"
FROM   shops s
LEFT   JOIN localities l ON l.id = s.locality_id
WHERE  s.locality_id = ANY (string_to_array('9c57227a-8f4e-44e0-a3a8-1439c25bf2e5,8f285bca-baec-442e-8a21-e067b75d8f13', ',')::uuid[])
AND    s.onboarding_status = 'ready'
GROUP  BY l.name;
```

I use `min(s.id)`, the smallest value in the group after grouping by `localities`. Adapt to your requirements. Maybe you want a separate group for each different `shops.id`?

```
...
GROUP  BY l.name, s.id;
```

If `shops.id` happens to be always the same for the same `localities.name` either variant ends up doing the same. (I would wonder about the functional dependency in the 2nd case, though ...)

Your original query would work if the column `name` was the PK of the table `localities`, because the PK covers the whole row. But not otherwise. See:

- [Why can't I exclude dependent columns from `GROUP BY` when I aggregate by a key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62096322/939860)

---

One more suspicious detail. You explained:

> which counts the number of `customer_events` for the current row's `localities.id`

But the query counts for `shops.id`, not for `localities.id`. One or the other is wrong.